# How can I use environment variables in haproxy.conf

Tags: haproxy, environment-variables

My haproxy.cfg file has one backend servers using hostnames:

```
backend servers
    server myapp ${PORTAL_PORT_3000_TCP_ADDR}:${PORTAL_PORT_3000_TCP_PORT} maxconn 32
```

myapp is running in other docker container linked to haproxy docker container. The mentioned environment variable have values inside haproxy container but when it container start raise this error

```
[ALERT] 244/134924 (8) : parsing [/etc/haproxy.cfg:16] : Unknown host in '${PORTAL_PORT_3000_TCP_ADDR}:${PORTAL_PORT_3000_TCP_PORT}'
[ALERT] 244/134924 (8) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 244/134934 (8) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

Comment: helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/668025/how-to-use-environment-variable-in-haproxy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are, most likely, using version 1.4 or older. The possibility to use environment variables has been introduced in haproxy 1.5.