# How to use environment variable in haproxy?

Tags: bash, load-balancing, haproxy

I work with haproxy 1.5.2
My haproxy.cfg has this server definitions:

```
server  HALB_ucd1 ${UCD1_END_POINT_IP}:${UCD1_END_POINT_PORT} check port 8444
```

I set the UCD1_END_POINT_IP and UCD1_END_POINT_PORT in the bash and 
start haproxy with service haproxy restart

The haproxy restarted OK but the UCD1_END_POINT_IP and UCD1_END_POINT_PORT are not resolved.
I see that as per haproxy doc it is supported:

```
    Any part of the address string may reference any number of environment 
   variables by preceding their name with a dollar sign ('$') and optionally 
   enclosing them with braces ('{}'),
   similarly to what is done in Bourne shell.
```

If I change it for hard coded ip and port it works fine.
What do I miss?

Thank you!

Comment: have you seen the following thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/693753/using-haproxy-environmental-variables-in-haproxy-cfg-not-working

Comment: Could you confirm which GNU/Linux distribution you are using? If, for example, the distribution uses `systemd` as its init system, `haproxy` will no be able to get environment variables from `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe try to use something like:

```
server  HALB_ucd1 "${UCD1_END_POINT_IP}:${UCD1_END_POINT_PORT}" check port 8444
```

Comment: Unfortunately the quotes raise an error  'server HALB_ucd1' : invalid address: '"' in '"$UCD1_END_POINT_IP:8444"'

Without quotes there is no error but the environment variable is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `env(variablename)`.

However, this option seems to only exist in 1.5+.

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.2-env