# Haproxy userlist password from an environment variable

Tags: haproxy

Is there a way to specify a password for the userlist from an environment variable. All of the following seem not to work:

```
userlist UsersFor_Frontend
  user admin insecure-password ${ENV_PASSWORD}
  user admin insecure-password env(ENV_PASSWORD)
  user admin insecure-password { env(ENV_PASSWORD) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do environment variables work in other parts of the conf file? If not, this is a duplicate, check
[How can I use environment variables in haproxy.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/625705/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-haproxy-conf#new-answer?newreg=b89a86e2ccb64c96bcd92a771397e648)
and
[Using HaProxy environmental variables in haproxy.cfg not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/693753/using-haproxy-environmental-variables-in-haproxy-cfg-not-working)

(Basically, you need to make sure you use ver >= 1.5, that the conf file is actually used and set the environment variables correctly - try "cat /proc/$(pgrep haproxy)/environ" - you should see the environment variables there.)

Comment: yes variables work in other parts. 

I use them for address and ports in the backend and I use them for an if for the acl (i.e the one to turn on or of basic auth). But I can not set the password. In all of the cases above the password ends up to be the string writen there i.e (${ENV_PASSWORD})